# C# set css to a System.windows.forms.webBrowser

Tags: c#, css, browser

Is it possible to set css to the webbrowser? If yes, than how Can I do this?

Let's say I have a class with 2 properties:

```
public String Css
```

and `public XElement Body`

I want to bind the body to a webbrowser and set the css of that webbrowser.

Is this possible and how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can assemble a string containing the complete HTML with a `<style>` tag, then set the `DocumentText` property to that string.